# php preg_replace regex leaving question mark artifacts

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of purposefully bad data.  I am attempting to strip out anything that is not basically something a user with a standard English keyboard would type, and also throw in a few spanish letters too for kicks:

```
$string = "ó�Ⲃⲟⲟⲉⲁⲛ ⲁⲛⲇ ⲒⲛϯⲉⲉꞅHôpitüD�sseldor ";
$re = '/[^\A-Za-z0-9@\.\' ;<>,-_\|!@#+=\[\]{}$%^&:*()"ñáéíóú]/mu';
$string = preg_replace($re, '', $string);
```

According to regex101, I should be getting back this as my result:

```
ó  HpitDsseldor
```

but instead I get back this:

```
ó???????? ??? ????????HpitD?sseldor
```

What is causing all of these `?` to remain in the cleaned output?

Comment: [It works as expected](https://3v4l.org/gI844).

Comment: Looks like you have an issue with different character encodings. You should fix that. Please start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through